# How to execute windows 'move' command in iPython window?

Tags: python, command, ipython, move

I have a simple script that I need to move a file from the current path to a new folder at the current path in iPython note book.

```
!move current_file_name NEW_FOLDER
```

current_file_name exists and NEW_FOLDER exists, however, I keep getting an error message

> "The system cannot find the file specified."

When I checked the validity of paths, they are all true.
This command works fine at the windows command prompt (without '!' sign).

My complete code :

```
import wget
MODEL_ZOO_NAME_PATH = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz'
model_zoo_name = wget.download(MODEL_ZOO_NAME_PATH)
if os.path.exists(model_zoo_name):
    print('Modal file name: ',model_zoo_name)
    !move model_zoo_name PRETRAINED_MODEL_PATH
    !cd {PRETRAINED_MODEL_PATH} && tar -zxvf model_zoo_name
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your move script with us?

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: I'm not sure what the !move and !cd means but maybe try using `shutil.move()`, `os.chdir()` and `subprocess.run()`?

Comment: '!' is to run command prompt commands inside ipython. Everything else works except 'move'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the actual `model_zoo_name` string value to the shell, not the
contents of that variable. Use `$model_zoo_name` or `{model_zoo_name}` to get the
contents (the second form supports arbitrary python expressions).